# Django state sharing between server processes

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I am building a Django project that one the of the apps has a state that I want to keep (a complex rate limiter as a Python Object that is hard to implement through something like Redis).

By making the server to spawn new processes like

```py
WSGIDaemonProcess localhost processes=2 threads=25
```

Will it cause to lose sync of the state between processes ? In standard python one will spin a Manager that proxies the state in multiple processes.

Comment: If you are running more than one WSGI process, make the stateless. Rate limiting in a complex architecture is a non-trivial topic.You will have to maintain a rate limiting bucket somewhere central.

Comment: @KlausD. Will having the rate limits inside an sqlite db be good ? The rate limit is for going hundreds of requests per second, but I don't know how good is sqlite at concurrency

Comment: Sqlite is designed for access by one process.

Comment: @KlausD. What other option do you recommend me for keeping the state "centralized"